# Find and replace string between quotes

Tags: python, regex, file-io

I'm reading a file and I would like to replace any text which appears between two double quotes like this:

If file input is:

> Hi, I'm an example file! "Hi there example file."
>
> "I'm mostly just here to get this quote to be colored!"

Output should be:

> Hi, I'm an example file! [color=x]"Hi there example file."[/color]
>
> [color=x]"I'm mostly just here to get this quote to be colored!"[/color]

I've wrote these three modules to do that, the first two work but the last doesn't.

Module 1:

```
__author__ = 'Joker'
import os
import sys
import re
import fileinput

print ("Text to search for:")
textToSearch = ( '" ' )

print ("Text to replace it with:")
textToReplace = ( '"[/color] ' )

print ("File to perform Search-Replace on:")
fileToSearch  = ( "D:\Coding projects\post edit\post.txt" )


tempFile = open( fileToSearch, 'r+' )

for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
    if textToSearch in line :
        print('Match Found')
    else:
        print('Match Not Found!!')
    tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
tempFile.close()

input( '\n\n Press Enter to exit...' )
```

Module 2:

```
__author__ = 'Joker'
import os
import sys
import re
import fileinput

print ("Text to search for:")
textToSearch = ( ' "' )

print ("Text to replace it with:")
textToReplace = ( ' [color=#66ccff]"' )

print ("File to perform Search-Replace on:")
fileToSearch  = ( "D:\Coding projects\post edit\post.txt" )

tempFile = open( fileToSearch, 'r+' )

for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
    if textToSearch in line :
        print('Match Found')
    else:
        print('Match Not Found!!')
    tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
tempFile.close()

input( '\n\n Press Enter to exit...' )
```

Module 3:

```
__author__ = 'Joker'
import os
import sys
import re
import fileinput

print ("Text to search for:")
textToSearch = ( r'\n"')

print ("Text to replace it with:")
textToReplace = (r'\n[color=#66ccff]"' )

print ("File to perform Search-Replace on:")
fileToSearch  = ( "D:\Coding projects\post edit\post.txt" )

tempFile = open( fileToSearch, 'r+' )

for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
    if textToSearch in line :
        print('Match Found')
    else:
        print('Match Not Found!!')
    tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
tempFile.close()

input( '\n\n Press Enter to exit...' )
```

**Bonus:** is there a way to combine the functionality of these three modules into one?

Comment: I already had the input in there. Added the output. Thanks for the heads-up (I did read the how to ask section.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) the `regular expression` module for that:

```
import re 

text = open(filename).read()  # read the entire file content

# define your tags here
opening_tag = '[color=x]'
closing_tag = '[/color]'

matches = re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"',text)  # match text between two quotes
for m in matches:
  text = text.replace('\"%s\"' % m, '%s\"%s\"%s' % (opening_tag, m, closing_tag))  # override text to include tags

# write modified text with tags to file
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
  f.write(text)

#  for the input you specified, the new file should be:
>> [color=x]"Hi there example file."[/color]
>> [color=x]"I'm mostly just here to get this quote to be colored!"[/color]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
line 15, in <module>
    f.write()
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Giving me an error, scratching my head to figure it out.

Comment: Updated answer @TheJoker.

Comment: Error is fixed, however none of the dialogue is being replaced inside my file by the new format after running the code. **Current code:** [link](http://puu.sh/nvtRK/577907ca59.png) **post.txt after running:** [link](http://puu.sh/nvtU1/1259f361d4.png) - The file got changed (since notepad++ asked to reload it.) But none of the contents was changed.

Comment: I found the problem. I just don't know the solution: In text.replace I think: '\"%s\"' % m - does not allow the script to recognize we want it to replace quotes with text inside by quotes with text inside surrounded by our tags.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using @Forge's answer as an inspiration. So major credits to him. However this is how I ended up fixing it. Including the final outcome:

```
import re 

string = open('post.txt').read()  # read the entire file content
cfile = open('character.txt').read() #Read character

#select a color
variable=raw_input('which character are you using?\n')
print variable
ini=cfile.find(variable)+(len(variable)+1)
rest=cfile[ini:]
search_enter=rest.find('\n')
color=str(rest[:search_enter])

# define your tags here
opening_tag = '[color=%s]' % (color)
closing_tag = '[/color]'

matches = re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"',string)  # match text between two quotes
for m in matches:
    string = string.replace('\"%s\"' % (m), '\"%s%s%s\"' % (opening_tag, m, closing_tag))  # override text to include tags

print string

# write tagged text to file
with open('post.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(string)
```